# SequelizeDatabaseError: Undeclared variable: NaN

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Why is my offset NaN? Everything works fine when I comment offset out of the find options. I know there are other questions like this, but none of them solve the problem.

```
exports.getProducts = (req, res, next) => {
let limit = 10, //10 products per page
    offset = 0; //no products skipped

Product.findAndCountAll()

    .then((data) => {
        let page = req.params.page ? parseInt(req.params.page) : 1,
            pages = Math.ceil(data.count / limit);
        offset = limit * (page - 1);
        console.log(offset)  //NaN
        console.log(typeof offset)  //number


        Product.findAll({
                limit: limit,
                offset: offset,
                include: [{
                    model: Order,
                    as: 'orders'
                }, {
                    model: User,
                    as: 'user'
                }]
            })
```

Comment: If `req.params.page` is a string like `'anything'` then `parseInt(req.params.page)` is `NaN` and `offset` is `NaN` as well

Comment: here is the url http://localhost:3000/search/1 how its gonna be string like that & i set fallback 1 if its not exist i can't catch the place it happens

Comment: Just show `JSON.stringify(req.params, null, 2)` content please

Comment: the error caused by chrome second request for favicon